# Handle Image in SCSS with Webpack

Tags: webpack

I have an issue when create webpack config

This is my config:

```
  module: {
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    use: {
      loader: "babel-loader",
      options: {
        presets: ['babel-preset-env']
      }
    }
  },
  {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    use: [
      MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
      "css-loader",
      "sass-loader"
    ]
  },
  {
    test: /\.(jp(e)?g|png|gif|svg)$/,
    use: {
      loader: 'url-loader',
      options: {
        limit: 8192,
        name: 'css/images/[name].[ext]'
      }
    }
  }
]
```

}

and this is file structure:

```
src/index.js
src/scss/style.scss
src/scss/component/header.scss
```

Content index.js

```
import "./scss/style.scss";
```

and this is index.scss

```
 @import "./components/header";
 body{
  background: url("./images/bg.jpg");
  color: red;
 }
```

header.scss

```
header{
  background: url('./images/headerbg.png');
}
```

After run then I got this issue:

```
ERROR in ./src/scss/style.scss (./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./src/scss/style.scss)
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './images/headerbg.png' in '/Volumes/MacData/Workspace/Projects/learncode/webpack/webpack02/src/scss'
     @ ./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./src/scss/style.scss 7:65-97
```

I dont know the reason, pls help me, thanks!

Comment: The reason is simple: there is a missing image `./images/headerbg.png` in `/Volumes/MacData/Workspace/Projects/learncode/webpack/webpack02/src/scss'`.

Comment: But, in header.scss i have added correct relative image url that's './images/headerbg.png'

Mean like this:

header.scss
images/headerbg.scss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for this issue: resolve-url-loader

This is docs for this issue: https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/#problems-with-url-